# VB.net Searching the date while removing the time in a Query

Tags: sql, vb.net

is this possible? i have like this.

> 16/01/17-12:20:58

inside my database and i want to search the date only. Is there a function inside the query like sub-string or is there any other option?

```
sql = "select * from qry where DateConduct between '" & dtFrom.Value.Date.ToString("yy-MM-dd") & "' and '" & dtTo.Value.Date.ToString("yy-MM-dd") & "'"
```

if possible i want something similar above. i'm using MS ACCESS as database.

Comment: Is `DateConduct` a string type column (i.e. char/varchar)?

Comment: a short text in my database

Comment: you cant store a date as a string and expect it to still act like a Date.  For the query, rather than trying to strip it off, you could use times which result in the entire day being included (ex 00:00:00 to 23.59.59 or 00:00:00 of the next day)

Comment: You really should not store dates in that way in a database. It's stupid. If you can, change the design of the table so that it has an actual date datatype. This should be your top priority. Fixing your code is while leaving a truly horrible design decision in your database is a waste.

Comment: @Tomalak yes i know, honestly i'm just helping a friend here. i just wondered if this is possible well if not then i have no choice but to change it's database and the code.

Comment: I know, but it's really the smartest decision here to switch the column to the proper datatype. You will help your friend a lot more by that than by just fixing the SQL and letting him go on with with what's essentially a broken database.

Answer (score 1):

(Please parameterise your query. It'll run faster and it's more secure.)

Your post doesn't specify a particular database platform. If you're on a recent version of SQL Server you have the DATE as well as DATETIME type, so can do

```
SELECT * FROM Qry WHERE CAST(DateConduct AS Date)=@DateParam
```

If you're on something older or different there's a number of techniques -

DATETIME is a FLOAT internally, so you can do CAST(TRUNCATE(CAST(DateVal AS Float)) AS DateTime) to get just the date component. Compare that with your date and you're good to go.

BETWEEN queries as you've seen can help. If you do

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE DateVAl BETWEEN @StartOfDay AND DATEADD(s,86399,@StartOFDay)
```

then you'll also get all the records for the day.

Comment: sorry for that i just update my question, I'm using MS Access for database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL date() function to return just the date part

Comment: is that possible inside the query? please take a look at my query

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the field as DATE or use the CONVERT function to compare only dates. I preffer CONVERT, always worked for me.

CAST.

```
sql = "select * from qry where CAST(DateConduct AS DATE) between '" & dtFrom.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "' and '" & dtTo.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "'"
```

CONVERT.

```
sql = "select * from qry where CONVERT(VARCHAR, DateConduct, 112) between '" & dtFrom.Value.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & "' and '" & dtTo.Value.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & "'"
```

Hope this helps. Best regards.

Comment: it says "Undefined function 'CONVERT' in expression." im using Access by the way.

Comment: Uh, sorry, but you tagged the post as SQL... Anyway, i'm not sure of how's Access syntax. You should or fix your database by changing the column type to datetime or look for some solution like "SELECT  CAST(LEFT(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112), 2) + DateConduct , 10) AS DATE) FROM qry"